# How to check when Glide removes an image from the cache?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am using Glide to load images. Currently, when the images are already loaded, they are saved into a cache and then fetched from it when asked for the same image again. But when the cache gets filled, does Glide delete the old files? If so, how do I know when it has done so and to which image?

```
    Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(new GlideUrl(url, new LazyHeaders.Builder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAuthorizationToken())
                    .build()))
            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>(width, height) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    eventEmitter.onPageRender(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151918/how-to-cache-images-in-glide

Comment: @Mar That didn't solve my problem. I want to know if there is a callback when the image is removed from cache.

Comment: if you mean memory cache, then just check if your bitmap is recycled. take note, it's not recommended to manipulatef your bitmap when using Glide. Glide will create a file cache for the image, don't think those ever get removed. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#isRecycled()